# Dynamicaly import specific dict from file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file containing lots of python dict. I want to load some of those dict as requested by the user. How cant I do that ?

my_dicts_file.py:

```
A = { 'value_a': 0,
      'value_b':'aa'}

B = { 'value_a': 10,
      'value_b':'bb',
      'value_c':'Nd'}

....
....

Z = { 'value_4': 50,
      'value_t':'0d'}
```

The following code does not work

```
for i in ['A','C']:
    from my_dicts_file import i
```

I don't want to load all the dicts if possible with

```
from my_dicts_file import *
```

Comment: I think that is impossible. With  `from A import B` you can import only one method or class. Not a variable

Comment: @Valeriy: Thats wrong. Of course you can import variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can do direct import like that, but I create some dummy example here.

```
import imp
my_dict = type('lambdaobject', (object, ), {})()
for i in ['A', 'C']:
    src = imp.load_source(i, 'my_dicts_file.py')
    setattr(mydict, i, getattr(src, i))
```

say if you're wanted to print variable A, you just

```
print my_dict.A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pickle the variables and then load when you need them. To do that you can use Python's pickle module